# How to convert a duration into a number of hours in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-spreadsheets

Trying to organize a timesheet. I have a cell with a duration of, say, 84:30:00
(84 hours, 30 mins, 0 seconds), which has a number format of "Duration".

How can I calculate the decimal number of hours (84.5) from this? The obvious approaches Hour(), Value() don't seem to work...

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Oh, you just multiply by 24 then format as a number. I guess durations are numerically stored as the number of days. Simple.

Comment: Very useful answer. But what a guess..!

Comment: The guess was super helpful! Thanks!